# What is the next version of Windows Server after Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Does anyone know what the next version of Windows Server after Server 2008 R2 is going to be called, and when it will be released?

Comment: Asking for predictions of the future really isn't a good fit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no name is set, but it's due to be released hopefully sometime in 2012

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/windows-8-roadmap-a-picture-is-worth-a-thousand-build-numbers/8747

Mary-Jo Foley's blog is a good way to keep up on release news
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft

Answer (score 0):

After some I research I found out that probably will be Windows Server “vNext”. See here for further reference:
[Will Windows 8 and Server "Next" to Be Developed in Parallel](http://windows8news.com/2010/06/08/windows-8-and-server-next-to-be-developed-in-parallel/)

Comment: That's a generic name Microsoft uses for their next version in a series, without giving away a version name. See: System Center Configuration Manager "vNext", or Office "vNext". It's just Microsoft speak.